# how to find most used classes in Visual Studio solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, code-metrics

Who knows how to find the most used classes (written/implemented, not referenced) in a Visual Studio solution? The solution contains a lot of projects. By 'most used' I mean the largest number of member invocations.

Thank you.

Comment: What counts as "most used"? That's a very unclear metric. Largest number of member invocations? Largest number of explicit mentions of the class name?

Comment: Most used classes are `System.String` and `System.Boolean` (even though it's a struct). The search is over.

Comment: Largest number of member invocations

Comment: What it will be used for? I can't think of any use.

Comment: I think this is a good question. One use case would be to find most central classes in the solution that a team might take on for most thorought analysis in a code review.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are certain tools like NDepend which my help you found how much classes are coupled together. Depending on Visual Studio version (ex. 2013 Ultimate) you can use Analyze tool to Calculate code metrics and see class coupling.
Personally I would go for NDpened as it gives you a lot of feedback about your solution and dependencies.

Comment: An example of query in NDepend to find most used classes:

from type in JustMyCode.Types
where type.NbTypesUsingMe > 0 && !type.IsInterface
orderby type.NbTypesUsingMe descending 
select new { type,  type.NbTypesUsingMe }